# Equations for $H_1(M)$ and $T$-Tate module of Anderson t-motive $M$ are equivalent: a reference?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, function-fields

What is a reference for the following construction?

Let $M$ be an Anderson t-motive of rank $r$ dimension $n$, i.e. a module over the Anderson ring $\mathbb{C}_\infty[T]\{\tau\}$ satisfying some conditions. Let $e_*:=(e_1,...,e_n)^t$ ($^t$ means transposition: a column matrix) be a basis of $M$ over $\mathbb{C}_\infty\{\tau\}$ and $f_*:=(f_1,...,f_r)^t$ a basis of $M$ over $\mathbb{C}_\infty[T]$.

Let $\mathfrak{A}\in GL_n(\mathbb{C}_\infty\{\tau\})$,
$$\mathfrak{A}=A_0+A_1\tau+A_2\tau^2+...+A_k\tau^k, \ \ \ A_i\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C}_\infty),$$ be a matrix defining the action of $T$ on $e_*$: $Te_*=\mathfrak{A}e_*.$
It defines the action of $T$ on $E(M)=(\mathbb{C}_\infty)^n$. For $x_*:=(x_1,...,x_n)^t\in (\mathbb{C}_\infty)^n$ we have
$$T(x_*)=A_0x_*+A_1x_*^{(1)}+A_2x_*^{(2)}+...+A_kx_*^{(k)}\qquad(1)$$
The $T$-Tate module of $M$ is a set of concordant sequences: $x_{*,0}=0,\ x_{*,1}, \ x_{*,2},...$ where $x_{*,i}\in E(M)$ such that $$T(x_{*,i})=x_{*,i-1}.\qquad(2)$$

Let $Q\in \mathrm{GL}_r(\mathbb{C}_\infty[T])$ be a matrix defining the action of $\tau$ on $f_*$: $$\tau f_*=Qf_*$$
$H_1(M)$ is the set of small elements in $\mathrm{Hom}(M, \mathbb{C}_\infty[[T]])^\tau$ (small means that the coefficients in $\mathbb{C}_\infty[[T]]$ tend to 0). For $\phi\in \mathrm{Hom}(M, \mathbb{C}_\infty[[T]])$ we define $Y=\phi(f_*)\in (\mathbb{C}_\infty[[T]])^r$ (a column vector). The condition of $\tau$-invariance of $\phi$ in terms of $Y$ is the following: $$Y^{(1)}Q=Y\qquad(3)$$

Conditions (2) (taking into consideration (1) ) and (3) (omitting condition of smallness) are equivalent, after some elementary transformations. What is a reference for this fact?

Answer (score 1):

For Drinfeld modules, this is proved in Pellarin's paper, "Aspects de l'indépendance algébrique en caractéristique non nulle," Astérisque (2007). See section 4.2.

For general Anderson $t$-modules that are abelian and uniformizable, it is contained in my paper with Namoijam, https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.05836. See (4.3.7) there. I believe if you take $Y = (\Upsilon^{tr})^{(-1)}$ and $Q = {\widetilde{\Phi}}^{tr}$ from our paper, it lines up with your equation (3).